# How exactly doctype works in browser? And how exactly xml namespaces work?

Tags: html, xml, jsf, primefaces, namespaces

Consider simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Which basically tells the browser to manipulate the tags according to some rules.. So are these rules really read from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd ? What if this site goes down?

Also, in a simple JSF page using Primefaces for example, you will start with:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

so that you can use p: tags and Primefaces components..

What exactly is "http://primefaces.org/ui" in here? Does it reference the primefaces.jar ? If so, how? Does it really connect to: "http://primefaces.org/ui" ?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you vote to close? reason?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Those are URIs – Uniform Resource **Identifiers**.

They serve as a unique identifier for a doctype or namespace, but they are not used with HTTP.

Comment: So what does the browser know about the xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" ?

Comment: @BalusC What do you mean? Sorry, I do not understand. I am a beginner.

Comment: @KorayTugay: It doesn't; that's server-side code.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, that is not the part I do not understand. What if I do not see it? My question is, how does server know that p: should be Primefaces components? How does it use that URI?